# Handling frequent database writes triggered by asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to store some data in a SQL Server database every time someone opens or refreshes a page of a website made in asp.net.
Should I try to buffer the inserts, writing them to the DB all together every X time, or is it acceptable to write them one by one?

I know I should provide some data about how many views I expect but the one who is supposed to tell me this has no idea... Here I'm just asking if there's any kind of best practice about handling frequent writes to a DB from an asp site. It's not a problem (logic wise) if the information insertion is delayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, but I don't think this is merely opinion, I would start off doing what was simplest and seemed most natural, without worrying about optimizations.

So if the server side page render event (probably not the actual event name) seems like a natural place to insert some records I would do just that.

If you're doing this on multiple pages then you might want to centralize the inserts using some sort of filter that all requests pass through (probably not the right term for asp.net either, but you get the idea).

Later on, if it turns out that doing this is introducing an unacceptable amount of latency, you can introduce some asynchronous way to update the database, perhaps a message queue or some of the c# ansync constructs.